# Will the given function be infinitely large?

Tags: limits, derivatives

> $$f(x)=\frac{cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x};x\rightarrow0$$

I computed the solution by:$$-1 \le cos(t) \le 1 $$,Therefore, $$\frac{cos(1/x)}{x}\rightarrow \infty$$
However, the asnwer is no.What is wrong with my above method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your solution, if the limit is infinity, then the given function *will* be infinitely large, so the answer would be yes.

In any case your solution is incorrect; the limit does not exist. This is because $\cos(1/x)$ will keep changing sign (it will be positive and negative and then positive again, etc.) as x goes to 0. This means that your function will oscillate (continuosly) between big positive values and big negative values.

This still means that the function will be infinitely large, so the answer is still yes (depending of course on how you define "the function will be infinitely large")